# Cannot run Azure Function 'Test' functionality from Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

I have a number of nodejs HTTP-triggered Azure Functions.

So far I was able to call test and pass a JSON, basically, making an HTTP request through Azure Portal UI. However, today I am getting this as an error with status: 500 (Internal Server Error):

`{ 
"Message": "Could not find a valid configuration for WebHook receiver 'genericjson' and instance '*fun-name*,default?code=*key*'. The setting must be set to a value between 32 and 128 characters long."
}`

Making an HTTP request not through Azure Portal works.

Is there a new breaking update?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm unable to repro this myself. Can you share your app name privately with me using the instructions [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)?

Comment: well, I hit this wall. There were some silly errors while pasting code from linqpad to function input. closing page and re-opening portal worked for me!

Comment: @mathewc, sorry for not answering. The issue is just happens here and there. In our team and in other teams that are suing Azure Functions, we switched to Postman for tests.